CSS Grid parent container overflow-x issue
In chrome devtools responsive (375px) i have this:
<div className="w-screen overflow-x-auto">
  <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(7,_100px)] bg-blue-200">
    <div className="sticky left-0 bg-green-200">col1</div>
    <div>col2</div>
    <div>col3</div>
    <div>col4</div>
    <div>col5</div>
    <div>col6</div>
    <div>col7</div>
  </div>
</div>

why is it that when i get to the 5:th column when scrolling in the x dimension that column starts to push col1 out of the viewport? 

Can you provide more code like css or something and a visible snippet that can be seen to address the issue? Thank you.

there's all there is really. The parent elements are:     
{children}


just reproduced this locally with this piece of code, but a snippet would have spared me some time

It looks react code.

@RajKumar it is.

<div className="w-screen overflow-x-auto">
  <div className="relative min-w-max">
    <div className="grid grid-cols-[repeat(7,100px)] bg-blue-200">
      <div className="sticky left-0 bg-green-200 z-10">col1</div>
      <div>col2</div>
      <div>col3</div>
      <div>col4</div>
      <div>col5</div>
      <div>col6</div>
      <div>col7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


You do not know both how to  ask questions and provide an answer.



 .overflow-x-auto {
            overflow-x: scroll;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 100px);
            grid-template-rows: 50px;
            background: lightblue;
        }

        .sticky {
            position: sticky;
            left: 0;
            background: green;
        }
<div class="overflow-x-auto">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="sticky">col1</div>
            <div>col2</div>
            <div>col3</div>
            <div>col4</div>
            <div>col5</div>
            <div>col6</div>
            <div>col7</div>
        </div>
    </div>



Here is the snippet without the tailwind stuff.
Here is a duplicate of your question:
Your problem is the lack of "width: max-content" on the grid container, the link above would describe this way better than me

yes, you're on to something here (min-width: max-content;). I ended up doing it like my own answer after checking with chat gpt.
